# What is the result of flagging a comment?

Tags: support

I was reading through some comments today and while trying to click a link in one, managed to inadvertently flag it.  This caused me to wonder what this does or means.

Apparently clicking it again does not toggle off the flag but flags it again.  Is there no way to undo an inadvertent one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes the site moderators aware of the flag.  They can then respond appropriately.

There is no way to undo a flag.  But don't worry, it will be handled by a human, who will decide whether the original flag had merit. And if not, no harm done.

Comment: Also, ["comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!